# Why there is no `leave` instruction at function epilog on x64?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86-64, red-zone

I'm on the way to get idea how the stack works on x86 and x64 machines. What I observed however is that when I manually write a code and disassembly it, it differs from what I see in the code people provide (eg. in their questions and tutorials). Here is little example:

**Source**

```
int add(int a, int b) {
    int c = 16;
    return a + b + c;
}

int main () {
    add(3,4);
   return 0;
}
```

**x86**

```
add(int, int):
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        sub     esp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 16
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+12]
        add     edx, eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-4]
        add     eax, edx
        leave (!)
        ret

main:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        push    4
        push    3
        call    add(int, int)
        add     esp, 8
        mov     eax, 0
        leave (!)
        ret
```

**Now goes x64**

```
add(int, int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        (?) where is `sub rsp, X`?
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-24], esi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 16
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        add     edx, eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        add     eax, edx
        (?) where is `mov rsp, rbp` before popping rbp?
        pop     rbp
        ret

main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     esi, 4
        mov     edi, 3
        call    add(int, int)
        mov     eax, 0
        (?) where is `mov rsp, rbp` before popping rbp?
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

As you can see, my main confusion is that when I compile against x86 - I see what I expect. When it's x64 - I miss leave instruction or exact following sequence: `mov rsp, rbp` then `pop rbp`. What's worng?

**UPDATE**

It seems like `leave` is missing, just because it wasn't altered previously. But then, goes another question - why there is no allocation for local vars in the frame?

---

To this question [@melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54781648/why-there-is-no-leave-instruction-at-function-epilog-on-x64#comment96342729_54781648) gives pretty straightforward answer - because of "red zone". Which basically means the function that calls no further functions (leaf) can use the first 128 bytes below the stack without allocating space. So if I insert a call inside an `add()` to any other dumb function - `sub rsp, X` and `add rsp, X` will be added to prologue and epilogue respectively.

Comment: Esp has not been changed so no action needed. Why to restore something unaffected

Comment: Yea, I see that now, right before you mentioned. I've updated post. Now, there is another question then..

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_%28computing%29.

Comment: what happens if you call a function inside add() ? e.g change it to `a + b+ c + f()` with `int f() { return 5;} `. I am curious what happens to `rsp` before the call to `f`. It should be adjusted otherwise local variables would be overwritten.

Comment: @AndreasH. It adds `push rbx; sub rsp, 16` to prologue and `add rsp, 16; pop rbx` to epilogue