# assembly epilogue composition

Tags: assembly, x86-64, stack-frame, red-zone, epilogue

I'm learning assembly, and I tried compiling the following C code into assembly with GCC with optimization disabled (https://godbolt.org/z/4cz3ocfa5)

```
void f() {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    int z = 3;
}

int main() {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

assembly,

```
f():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 2
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 3
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        call    f()
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

I'm confused why where is no `mov rsp, rbp` before the `pop` instruction in the epilogue (especially when there are local variables in the stack frame of `f`).
I thought a complete epilogue should be like

```
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

[image]

Comment: RSP is already equal to RBP; a `mov` would be redundant and the compiler knows that because it generated the code.  This is possible because it put the variables in the red zone below RSP, a feature of the x86-64 System V ABI.  Use `-mno-red-zone` if you want it not to take advantage of that and match your traditional stack layout diagrams.

Comment: Another duplicate: [Why there is no \`leave\` instruction at function epilog on x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54781648)